# Jquery loop through elements and set width

Tags: jquery, foreach

I have pagination inside each tab in a show/hide tab box. I need to set the with on each .pagination element depending on the number of items in that tab. I have this code which appears to work in the first tab but doesn't set the width of pagination in each of the subsequent ones.

```
$('.tab_content').each(function() {
        var liNum = $('.pagination li',this).size();
        var liWidth = $('.pagination li',this).outerWidth() + 2;
        var paginationwidth = liNum * liWidth;

        $('.pagination',this).width(paginationwidth);
    });
```